# Stop IE from redirecting before downloading a file

Tags: internet-explorer, download, kohana

I am having a problem only with IE (tested in 8) and downloading, when i click the link it takes me to the server that the file is on before downloading it. The correct behavior should be that the file download option pops up and the page is not redirected.

I am using a Kohana $this->request->redirect($file) to do the download.

Any ideas on why this would happen?

developing on localhost

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Response::send_file()` for what you're trying to do.

```
$this->response->send_file('path/to/file.ext');
```

You can also use the current response object for this:

```
$this->response->send_file(TRUE,'download_file_name.ext');
```